# Using CloudWatch Event : How to Pass JSON Object to CodeBuild as an Environment Variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Summary: I can't specify a JSON object using CloudWatch target Input Transformer, in order to pass the object contents as an environment variable to a CodeBuild project.

Background:
I trigger an AWS CodeBuild job when an S3 bucket receives any new object. I have enabled CloudTrail for S3 operations so that I can use a CloudWatch rule that has my S3 bucket as an Event Source, with the CodeBuild project as a Target.

If I setup the 'Configure input' part of the Target, using Input Transformer, I can get single 'primitive' values from the event using the format below:

Input path textbox:

```
{"zip_file":"$.detail.requestParameters.key"}
```

Input template textbox:

```
{"environmentVariablesOverride": [ {"name":"ZIP_FILE", "value":<zip_file>}]}
```

*And this works fine if I use 'simple' single strings.*

However, for example, if I wish to obtain the entire 'resources' key, which is a JSON object, I need to have knowledge of each of the keys within, and the object structure, and manually recreate the structure for each key/value pair.

For example, the resources element in the Event is:

```
"resources": [
            {
                "type": "AWS::S3::Object",
                "ARN": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/myfile.zip"
            },
            {
                "accountId": "1122334455667799",
                "type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
                "ARN": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
            }
        ],
```

I want the code in the buildspec in CodeBuild to do the heavy lifting and parse the JSON data.

If I specify in the input path textbox:

```
 {"zip_file":"$.detail.resources"}
```

Then CodeBuild project never gets triggered.

Is there a way to get the entire JSON object, identified by a specific key, as an environment variable?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the detail. My use case is just your simple element transform, solved by your question exposition. Its so hard to find examples of simple AWS service use cases.

Comment: environmentVariablesOverride is crucial, which Is why i could never get it to work until I found this Q/A. Now I can find that the Codebuild docs have it https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/APIReference/API_StartBuild.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this...CodeBuild targets support all the parameters allowed by StartBuild API. You need to use environmentVariablesOverride in your JSON string.

```
{"environmentVariablesOverride": [ {"name":"ZIPFILE", "value":<zip_file>}]}
```

Please,avoid using '_' in the environment name.

Comment: I use that method already (see the original question), and it works fine with '_' in the environment variable name.

Comment: This does not, in any way, answer the question.